# Musical Instruments of the Levi'im

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash, music, levites-leviyim

Does there appear anywhere in Torah Sheb'al Peh a sufficiently detailed description of the musical instruments played by the Levi'im in the Beit Hamikdash that they could theoretically be reconstructed and played?

Comment: https://www.templeinstitute.org/harp-gallery.htm - https://www.templeinstitute.org/lyre-gallery.htm -

Comment: According to many, the Shofar is considered a musical instruments and so are the *Hatzotzrot* (trumpets). Talmud Rosh Hashannah near its beginning describes both.

Comment: The chatzotzros (trumpets) are shown at http://www.templeinstitute.org/vessels_gallery_17.htm Shofar http://www.templeinstitute.org/vessels_gallery_17.htm

Comment: @DanF I guess I did know about the descriptions of the shofar and the chatzotzrot. I am more curious about the nevel and the kinnor.

Comment: Side point, isn't there an issur somewhere about replicating the keilim? So even if you knew what they looked like, shouldn't that prevent you from making them?

Comment: @DonielF http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22395/759 Can you also not make spoons?

Comment: Alright, fair enough. I'm not sure I hear the Chinuch's proof of salka daytach amina that you can't make spoons. Maybe ein hacha nami, we should use deformed cups to scoop soup out of our bowls.

Answer (score 2):

The Temple Institute claims to have reconstructed many of the holy artifacts required by the Bais Hamikdash

The [chatzotzros (trumpets)](http://www.templeinstitute.org/vessels_gallery_17.htm), [Gold plated Shofar](http://www.templeinstitute.org/vessels_gallery_18.htm), 
[Silver Plated Shofar](http://www.templeinstitute.org/vessels_gallery_19.htm),
[Harp](http://www.templeinstitute.org/vessels_gallery_20.htm),
[Lyre](http://www.templeinstitute.org/vessels_gallery_21.htm)

Comment: Do you happen to know if they have a source for constructing the harp and the lyre as they did?

Comment: @Ze'ev You would have to check their web site and contact them to get the details.

Comment: @Ze'ev they use whatever limited archeological evidence is available, and fill in the gaps with contemporaneous artifacts. Their kinnor is based off a coin dating from the bar kochba period.

Comment: OTOH, a magreifah is anything from a portable pipe organ to something like an accordion or maybe a bagpipe. The descriptions in the Yerushalmi, Sukkah 5:6. It has 10 holes, or 10 pipes -- or 10 pipes that have 10 holes each, was capable of playing chords, and a 1 ammah cube sized thing that blew air. I don't think the Temple Institute will guess at that one quite yet. (The same word, magreifah, means the rakes used to clean the coals and ash off the altar. Which may refer to a visual similarity if the pipes were splayed like the ribs of a hand-fan.)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the Mishnah in Erchin (Arachin, if you insist) on daf 10a and Mishnah and Gemara later on 13b. Rashi there discusses what, exactly, the various instruments were.

Comment: Does  he give "a sufficiently detailed description of the musical instruments played by the Levi'im in the Beit Hamikdash that they could theoretically be reconstructed and played"?

Comment: He tells you what they are. Don't we all know what cymbals look like?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to find there are [multiple kinds of cymbals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cymbal#List_of_cymbal_types), and even less surprised to find there are multiple kinds of harps. Knowing the name isn't necessarily sufficient (unless you can prove that all variations of harps are equally kosher)

Comment: Well, Rashi *does* say both a kinor and a neivel are types of harps...

Comment: Ok so that supports that the particular type is relevant. What if we bring lots of harps to the Mikdash and it turns out they are all Kinnorim and not Nevalim?